# Radio Buttons with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following coded radio buttons, which  retrieve value(s) in the code below. 
Is it possible to create hyperlink references from these retrieved values e.g., google.com and/or yahoo.com for the selected radio buttons?

```
<script language="javascript">
<!--

function RadioCheck() {


var selection = document.quiz.colour;

for (i=0; i<selection.length; i++)

  if (selection[i].checked == true)
 alert(selection[i].value);




}

//-->
</script>



</head>
<body>

<form name="quiz">

  <input type="radio" name="colour" value="red">red<br>
  <input type="radio" name="colour" value="orange">orange<br>
  <input type="radio" name="colour" value="yellow">yellow<br>
 <br>


<input type="submit" value="Check Answer" onClick="RadioCheck()">

</form>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you want to link to google, and with what URLs specifically?

Comment: was there supposed to be code there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if 'red' should redirect to Google, but in case you'd like this, code along the lines of:

```
<input type="radio" name="colour" value="http://google.com/">red<br>
```

and then in JavaScript:

```
if (selection[i].checked == true)
location.href = selection[i].value;
```

So instead of alerting the value, you navigate to the value, which has been set to some website.

You would also need to cancel the real submitting: http://jsfiddle.net/HDL7J/.

Comment: it is not navigating just reloading page again.

Comment: i change it like this but it is navigating on selection of radio button but after selection he has to hit submit button to move forward.<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

function go(loc) {
window.location.href = loc;
}

</script>

</HEAD>



<BODY>

<form name="form">
<input type="radio" name="loc" onClick="go('http://www.google.com/');"> google<br>
<input type="radio" name="loc" onClick="go('http://www.yahoo.com/');"> yahoo<br>
<input type="radio" name="loc" onClick="go('http://www.facebook.com/');"> facebook<br>

</form>

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="group" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://google.com'; return true;" />
```